# What does it mean to hate your life and keep it for eternity?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-john

John 12:25

> Anyone who loves their life, will lose it while anyone who hates their life in this world will keep it for eternal life.

What is Jesus actually saying? Why would I, hating my now life, want to keep it for eternity?

Can you simply explain just what it is Jesus is saying to those of us who love him?